# AS3 - Is it possible to test objects in the same array against each other?

Tags: actionscript-3, collision-detection, hittest

I am making this project that allows the player to push objects. I can test the player against the object array just fine using the "for" loop and I can move the objects around.

What I want to do now is test the objects against each other and have them move each other as well. Like, I want to push a block with the player and then push another block with the block I'm already pushing.

The blocks are all pushed into their own arrays, so how could I test them against each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can place everything in the same array and use two `for` loops:

```
for each(var a:Entity in array)
{
    for each(var b:Entity in array)
    {
        // Objects can't collide with themselves.
        if(a == b) continue;


        // Check if a and b collide and do something.
        //
    }
}
```

This example code assumes that `Entity` is a base class for your objects that can touch each other; all of which are listed within `array`.

Comment: That worked for what I'm doing now. Funny thing, though. Objects that are added to the array later cannot be used to push objects that are added to the array earlier. They glitch out and suddenly appear above the early objects. like "object A" is added to the array and to the stage before "object B". I cannot use object B to push object A. Instead, object B appears in some odd position next to object A. Any idea as to what's up with that?

Comment: @JosephWagner That would be related to your collision management code. You need to be careful that your code doesn't rely on the order in which you check the collision.